# Send email to user when activated, using workflow rule

Tags: trigger, email, email-alert, workflowrule

How can I configure Salesforce to send an email to a user when its user in the system is activated (`IsActive = true`)?

Right now I can create a workflow rule that triggers when the User record is changed, and specify to run when the `IsActive` field is set to true, but when I try to create the Email Alert, I don't see a way to inform that I want the email to be sent to that user.

I only get these options:

[image]

But none of them seem to fit. I tried using the 'Email Field' one, but it doesn't work.

Since I tried this, I thought of doing it with a trigger too, but when I send the notification email, the email simply does not arrive at my inbox. No errors are thrown, the Deliverability is ok, and the code works when I run it from the console.

I'm calling this method in an afterUpdate trigger on User:

```
public void notifyUser() {
    EmailUtils email_utils = new EmailUtils();
    EmailTemplate template = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName = 'UsuarioAtivado' LIMIT 1];

    Map<Id, User> oldmap = (Map<Id, User>) Trigger.oldMap;
    List<Id> activated_users_ids = new List<Id>();

    for (User u : (List<User>) Trigger.new) {
        if (oldMap.containsKey(u.Id) && !oldMap.get(u.Id).IsActive && u.IsActive) {
            System.debug('User activated. [' + u.Id + ']');
            activated_users_ids.add(u.Id);
        }
    }

    List<User> usuarios_ativados = [SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN :activated_users_ids];

    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(usuarios_ativados.size());

    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();

    for (User u : usuarios_ativados) {
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage sem = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        sem.setTemplateId(template.Id);
        sem.setSaveAsActivity(false);
        sem.setOrgWideEmailAddressId(email_utils.addresses.get('CompanyName'));
        sem.setTargetObjectId(u.Id);
        emails.add(sem);
        System.debug('Email:');
        System.debug(sem);
    }

    Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
}
```

Comment: Could you tell please, what didn't work for email field in workflow? And since both - workflow and trigger don't work, I would suggest you to check an e-mail address on user. Also, write `System.debug(Messaging.sendEmail(emails));` instead of `Messaging.sendEmail(emails);` to check the results. And after that look into debug logs - it could be that your trigger doesn't fire the code.

Comment: I've collected the SendResult, and iterated over it. It is always successful (`isSuccess()` returns true).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am able to see the Email field of User in Email Alert and this is working. The specified email received email once User has been activated using Workflow.

[image]

Comment: I am able to select it as well. Didn't get to the point where I had an answer typed up but this is almost exactly what it would have looked like.

Comment: Eeeeh. I might have forgotten to activate the workflow rule. Thanks. One thing still bothers me though: the trigger didn't work, and it is doing the exact same thing as the workflow rule.